# run storm nimbus get error

Tags: python-2.7, apache-storm

when i run  storm nimbus or other storm command i get the same error

```
~/work/apache-storm-0.9.5/bin$ storm nimbus
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/libin/work/apache-storm-0.9.5/bin/storm", line 514, in <module>
main()

File "/home/libin/work/apache-storm-0.9.5/bin/storm", line 511, in main
(COMMANDS.get(COMMAND, unknown_command))(*ARGS)

File "/home/libin/work/apache-storm-0.9.5/bin/storm", line 308, in nimbus
jvmopts = parse_args(confvalue("nimbus.childopts", cppaths)) + [
File "/home/libin/work/apache-storm-0.9.5/bin/storm", line 113, in confvalue
p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
```

edit: i modify my javahome as @helloV said,but get the same mistake

Comment: tell me, how you have set JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 2):

Check your JAVA_HOME. I had the same issue. My JAVA_HOME was pointing to a wrong dir. Once I set JAVA_HOME correctly, the problem went away.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_17
```

Comment: i also modify it as your said ,but not success.  echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_51